# Стилизация диалога

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-style

Есть диалог-фрагмент, сейчас он выводится вот так:
http://i7.5cm.ru/i/aLZ0.png

Необходимо вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понятны две вещи:

Почему в диалоге сверху белая полоса, откуда она взялась и как ее убрать?

Каким образом сделать ширину под макет, без затемнения, и желательно между итемами?

p.s. Вызываться диалог должен, внимание: из боковой шторки.

XML диалога:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2196f3"
    android:id="@+id/rate_dialog"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok_sure"
        android:id="@+id/btn_dialog_yes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_dialog_no"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_dialog_no"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_thanks"
        android:id="@+id/btn_dialog_no"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_dialog_yes"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_dialog_yes"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you like Power Thesaurus?"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_dialog_no"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_dialog_no"
        android:layout_marginRight="51dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="51dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Код диалога:

```
public class RateAppFragmentDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

   @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rate_dialog,null);

        return view;
    }
```

В `MainActivity` я просто создаю экземпляр, и передаю ему `getSupportFragmentManager()` и tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта "белая полоса" - title.

Чтобы убрать title из диалога, добавьте в onCreateView() такую строку

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Чтобы сделать фон прозрачным:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Разместить диалог между итемами вы можете попробовать только вручную рассчитав, где начинается нужный item, и выставив у диалога отступ.

Answer (score 2):

Убрать белую полоску можно так

`dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Если вы хотите делать между итемами, без затемнения и в ширину экрана, то вам следует отказаться от диалога, а расширять item_view при клике (или какое у вас там событие?)